Decay of Fourier coefficients of a function on the disk
What can be said about the decay of the Fourier coefficients of a smooth function on the unit disk $B_1(0)$? More precisely, I'm in the following setting:
Let $v \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(B_1(0), \mathbb{R})$. Then, we can express the function by its Fourier expansion in the angular coordinate, i.e.
$$
\begin{align}
v(r, \theta) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{v}_m(r) e^{im\theta}.
\end{align}
$$
For such a function to me continuous, we require that for all $m \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ that $\hat{v}_m(r) \to 0$ for $r \to 0$.
But how does the smoothness relate to the behavior of the Fourier coefficients? My intuition is that all radial derivatives must be independent of the angle $\theta$ at the origin and therefore the derivatives of the Fourier coefficients of the non-zero modes must vanish at the origin too. Is this statement correct?
I am also curious about a Riemann-Lebesgue-type result with respect to the radial coordinate, i.e. are there any estimates of the form $|\hat{v}_m(r)| = \mathcal{O}(|r|^{\lambda_m})$ for some positive exponent $\lambda_m > 0$?
